# Vite + React + Wallet Adapter

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, react, vite

Trying to use the simplest example, getting `react-dom.development.js:22839 Uncaught TypeError: off is not a function` error.
Below the code, error and `vite.config.ts`.

```
import './App.css'
import {Wheel} from "./components/Wheel.tsx";
import {Table} from "./components/Table.tsx";
import {useMemo} from 'react';
import {ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import {WalletAdapterNetwork} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import {
    WalletModalProvider,
    WalletDisconnectButton,
    WalletMultiButton
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import {clusterApiUrl} from '@solana/web3.js';

// Default styles that can be overridden by your app
// import('@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css');

function App() {
    const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;
    const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

    const wallets = useMemo(
        () => [],
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        [network]
    );

    return (
        <>
            <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
                <WalletProvider wallets={wallets}>
                    <WalletModalProvider>
                        <WalletMultiButton/>
                        <WalletDisconnectButton/>
                        <div className={"bg-gray-700 p-3"}>
                            <Wheel/>
                            <Table/>
                        </div>
                    </WalletModalProvider>
                </WalletProvider>
            </ConnectionProvider>
        </>
    );
}

export default App
```

```
react-dom.development.js:22839 Uncaught TypeError: off is not a function
    at StandardWalletAdapter.destroy (adapter.ts:125:13)
    at useStandardWalletAdapters.ts:40:73
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at useStandardWalletAdapters.ts:40:44
    at safelyCallDestroy (react-dom.development.js:22932:5)
    at commitHookEffectListUnmount (react-dom.development.js:23100:11)
    at invokePassiveEffectUnmountInDEV (react-dom.development.js:25207:13)
    at invokeEffectsInDev (react-dom.development.js:27351:11)
    at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:27324:7)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27056:5)
destroy @ adapter.ts:125
(anonymous) @ useStandardWalletAdapters.ts:40
(anonymous) @ useStandardWalletAdapters.ts:40
safelyCallDestroy @ react-dom.development.js:22932
commitHookEffectListUnmount @ react-dom.development.js:23100
invokePassiveEffectUnmountInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:25207
invokeEffectsInDev @ react-dom.development.js:27351
commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:27324
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27056
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 14 more frames
Show less
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <WalletProvider> component:

    at WalletProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-VGC3ZBUC.js?v=92d76a06:2382:27)
    at ConnectionProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-VGC3ZBUC.js?v=92d76a06:222:29)
    at App (http://localhost:5173/src/App.tsx?t=1697008814030:29:20)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27060
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 18 more frames
Show less
react-dom.development.js:12056 Uncaught TypeError: off is not a function
    at StandardWalletAdapter.destroy (adapter.ts:125:13)
    at useStandardWalletAdapters.ts:40:73
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at useStandardWalletAdapters.ts:40:44
    at safelyCallDestroy (react-dom.development.js:22932:5)
    at commitHookEffectListUnmount (react-dom.development.js:23100:11)
    at invokePassiveEffectUnmountInDEV (react-dom.development.js:25207:13)
    at invokeEffectsInDev (react-dom.development.js:27351:11)
    at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:27324:7)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27056:5)
```

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import {NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin} from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import {NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin} from "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill";
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            // Node.js global to browser globalThis
            define: {
                global: "globalThis",
            },
            // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
            plugins: [
                NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                    process: true,
                    buffer: true,
                }),
                NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
            ],
        },
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            plugins: [
                // Enable rollup polyfills plugin
                // used during production bundling
                rollupNodePolyFill(),
            ],
        },
    },
})
```